# Can you dispel Suffocation and Mass Suffocation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Can the *suffocation* and *mass suffocation* spells be dispelled?

> This spell extracts the air from the target's lungs, causing swift
>   suffocation.
>
> The target can attempt to resist this spell's effects with a Fortitude
>   save-if he succeeds, he is merely staggered for 1 round as he gasps
>   for breath. If the target fails, he immediately begins to suffocate.
>   On the target's next turn, he falls unconscious and is reduced to 0
>   hit points. One round later, the target drops to -1 hit points and is
>   dying. One round after that, the target dies. Each round, the target
>   can delay that round's effects from occurring by making a successful
>   Fortitude save, but the spell continues for 3 rounds, and each time a
>   target fails his Fortitude save, he moves one step further along the
>   track to suffocation. This spell only affects living creatures that
>   must breathe. It is impossible to defeat the effects of this spell by
>   simply holding one's breath-if the victim fails the initial Saving
>   Throw, the air in his lungs is extracted.

If I understand these spells correctly, the spell empties the lungs and prevents breathing… so if I am correct, it is an ongoing effect, even if it is quickly lethal.

So can you dispel this effect if you react quickly enough?

I am thinking about something like this: Enemy casts *suffocation* on fighter, fighter fails his save, he suffocates, but is still conscious and with his hp > 0, wizard dispels the suffocation effect, fighter breathes, and doesn't fall unconscious at 0 hp.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, you can dispel *Suffocation* before its normal duration ends.** It has a duration of 3 rounds, therefore someone would need to dispel it before time is up. So, what actually happens when you successfully dispel it? If [*Dispel Magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic) succeeds, then the Suffocation spell goes away; however, if HP was lost, it is not instantly recovered.

> You can use *dispel magic* to end one ongoing spell that has been cast on a creature or object, to temporarily suppress the magical abilities of a magic item, or to counter another spellcaster's spell. A dispelled spell ends as if its duration had expired.

So the spell ends, but is not undone, because "reduced to 0 hit points" is not a removable condition. The victim is unconscious when they are at 0 HP, or dying when they are at -1 HP.

In your example, if the *Suffocation* effect is dispelled before the fighter drops to 0 HP, then the spell ends and the fighter is fine.

However, if the *Suffocation* effect is dispelled after the fighter falls unconscious, then the fighter is still at 0 HP (which probably means they are also unconscious).

Comment: some items or feats, like the ring of delayed doom delay the effect of save or die.

Comment: sorry MissClick. Can you dispel effect delayed that way ? What about other spells like flesh to stone or power word kill delayed that way ? And with other means of dispel like the barbarian's spell sunder rage power ?

Comment: Plus once the effect is dispelled the target, even if unconscious, can breathe again and get air back into their lungs.